# CMDBuild SSO implementation with CAS

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I am trying to implement SSO in CMDBuild by using CAS. I have installed CMDBuild and CAS in my local centos 6.5 machine. But i am unable to do SSO successfully.

Environmental Details are stated below

Centos 6.5

CAS 4.2.0

CMDBuild 2.4.1

My Cas configuration inside auth.conf is

auth.methods=CasAuthenticator,DBAuthenticator

```
cas.server.url=https://localhost:8443/cas

cas.login.page=/login

cas.service.param=http://localhost:8080/cmdbuild/index.jsp

cas.ticket.param=ticket
```

But while i try to access cmdbuild from browser after changing the configuration. Some parameters are appending to the URL like below which causes cmdbuild not to start.

https://localhost:8443/cas/login?http://localhost:8080/cmdbuild/index.jsp=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.50.161%3A8080%2Fcmdbuild%2Findex.jsp%3Fskipsso

Also in CMDBuild log i found the same error,

INFO  2016-09-21 08:35:44 [cmdbuild] trying to login with no username or password

INFO  2016-09-21 08:35:44 [cmdbuild] Redirecting to https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.50.161%3A8080%2Fcmdbuild%2Findex.jsp%3Fskipsso

As per the documentation,

"The CAS authenticator sends the request to the CAS server (${cas.server.url} + $ {cas.login.page}) specifying the CMDBuild access url (in the ${cas.service.param} paramter)"

I have configured CMDBuild access url in cas.service.param

I am having some doubts on what i have to configure in cas.service.param and cas.ticket.param. What i have to add in cas.service.param and cas.ticket.param.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.3.2 at least, these are the correct key values:

```
./cmdbuild.sh restws setconfig org.cmdbuild.auth.modules=cas
./cmdbuild.sh restws setconfig org.cmdbuild.auth.module.cas.server.url=https://…
./cmdbuild.sh restws setconfig org.cmdbuild.auth.module.cas.login.page=/login
./cmdbuild.sh restws setconfig org.cmdbuild.auth.module.cas.service.param=service
./cmdbuild.sh restws setconfig org.cmdbuild.auth.module.cas.ticket.param=ticket
```